# Additional fields retrieved while using reflection

Tags: methods, reflection

I am writing a simple java class that makes use of the reflection API to find out the declared fields in the java.lang.class. Following is the piece of java code I have written.

```
Field[] fields = String.class.getDeclaredFields();

for (Field f : fields) {
    System.out.println("Field name: " + f.getName());
}
```

I am getting the following output when I run this program.

```
Field name: serialVersionUID
Field name: CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
Field name: ascii
Field name: stringArray
Field name: stringArraySize
Field name: enableCopy
Field name: value
Field name: offset
Field name: count
Field name: hashCode
Field name: hashCode32
Field name: seed
Field name: startCombiningAbove
Field name: endCombiningAbove
Field name: upperValues
Field name: serialPersistentFields
```

When I looked at the source code of the String class, I found that there were only 6 fields defined for the class in API.

I am not able to figure out where these additional fields are coming from in the output. Please help here.

Comment: I also came across some weird results while I tried to retrieve the fields defined for a java.util.HashMap class. It did not return fields that are defined as transient (table, size).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code; when I run it, I get the expected output:

```
Field name: value
Field name: hash
Field name: serialVersionUID
Field name: serialPersistentFields
Field name: CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
```

I'm guessing that you're using a non-Oracle Java Virtual Machine that adds (either in its bundled libraries or through some runtime magic) adds some nonstandard fields to the `String` class.

Comment: Can you please tell the which JDK and what version are you using ?
However, I got what you meant to say here. I tried from few other JDKs (non-oracle) and I could see the difference as you mentioned.

Comment: `java -version` gives: 
`java version "1.8.0_45"`
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)`
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)`